# Why do whiskers not equal quantile?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, plotly

I'm not sure if this is not actually a mathematical question, but why doesn't plotly boxplot whiskers equal the panda data frame method `quantile(0.01)` or `(0.99)` or similar? The reason is definetly not, that the quantile parameter doesn't match, because some calculations result higher and others lower.
thx

```
for col in df.columns:

    data.append(  go.Box( y=df[col], name=getclearname(col), showlegend=False, boxmean='sd' ) )
    df.rename(columns = {col:getclearname(col)}, inplace = True)
    df=df.fillna(100)
    #print(df)
data.append( go.Scatter( x = df.columns, y = df.median(), mode='marker', name='median' ) )
data.append( go.Scatter( x = df.columns, y = df.quantile(0.25), mode='marker', name='lower quantile' ) )
data.append( go.Scatter( x = df.columns, y = df.quantile(0.75), mode='marker', name='upper quantile' ) )
data.append( go.Scatter( x = df.columns, y = df.fillna(100).quantile(0.01), mode='marker', name='lower percentile' ) )
data.append( go.Scatter( x = df.columns, y = df.fillna(100).quantile(0.99), mode='marker', name='upper percentile' ) )
layout=go.Layout(title=""+cata+" - local spatial properties on placements<br>"+constraintdesc,yaxis=dict(
    title='percentage of range between flat extremes'))
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.offline.iplot(fig, filename='pandas-box-plot')
```

results in the following strange behaviour:
[downloaded plot from notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0sMg.png)

Comment: Could you make an example with one column and post the data? AFAIK, plotly boxplots draw whiskers based on IQR by default. Do you expect them to extend to full range of data?

Comment: @gereleth its based on a quite complex query from a db resulting in a comprehensive set of thousands of rows - I suggest to generate a random column with a range from 0-100 - it should result in the same. I expect the whiskers y-value to be exactly equal to a defined quantile... the box plots lower an upper quartile already equals exactly.
I hope I didn't get you wrong...

Comment: See the [Styling Outliers](https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/#styling-outliers) example in plotly docs. I'm guessing you want the boxplot with `boxpoints=False`, but the question isn't clear enough to be sure. I'll just leave the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link here =).